# Datatables fnGetData returns different object from table row

Tags: javascript, datatables

I have this function

```
var table = $(tableId);
var datatable = table.dataTable();  
table.on('click', 'i.pointerCursor', function() {
            var $this = $(this),
                tr = $(this).closest( 'tr' ).get(0);
            if ( datatable.fnIsOpen(tr) ) {
                $this.removeClass( 'fa-minus-square-o' ).addClass( 'fa-plus-square-o' );
                datatable.fnClose( tr );
            } else {
                $this.removeClass( 'fa-plus-square-o' ).addClass( 'fa-minus-square-o' );

                console.log(tr);
                console.log(datatable.fnGetData(tr));

                datatable.fnOpen( tr, self.dataTableFormatRow( datatable,tr,$this[0].attributes[0].textContent), 'details' );


            }
        });
```

I am logging out the tr and the datatable.fnGetData(tr), because I would need the row as an object. The tr returns the actual row, but when I pass this tr to the datatable.fnGetData(), it always returns a totally different object. And this object seems always the same, even if I click on a different row.

I can't figure it out, why this is. How could I fix this? Or should I replace the code?

Comment: I have the feeling that you are not showing us all the code.  `fnGetData` *will* return either an array or an object for the `<tr>` node in question.

Comment: That would be too much code :) Basically first I am building the datatable, which is empty. Then after pageload I'm adding the data to it.
Even if I removed and added the listener again, it behaves the same way

Comment: Hey @pape04, wrote this because your problem not is reproceable. Somewhere you mess up the `tr` reference, I believe.

Comment: @davidkonrad Thank you. Probably you are right. I just don't know where it gets messed up. I will try to find it. I noticed it is always returning the last row's data.